# Link not working when used with jquery scrollpath

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I know this might be a very simple and stupid fix, but I can't find the answer and it's driving me crazy.

Just take a look at http://mozlo.com/zabzie/

If you click on any link in the top nav, they're dead. If I disable jquery.scrollpath.js , it works as expected, but the thing is I need that script. Any idea on how to solve this issue? I tried everything I could think of to no avail, any help appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Fabio

Comment: I get `$ is not defined` on line 15 when I go to that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
// Add scrollTo on click on the navigation anchors
$("nav").find("a").each(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Include the jQuery easing plugin (http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)
        // for extra easing functions like the one below
        $.fn.scrollPath("scrollTo", target, 1000, "easeInOutSine");
    });
});
```

to:

```
// Add scrollTo on click on the navigation anchors
$("nav#panelnav").find("a").each(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Include the jQuery easing plugin (http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)
        // for extra easing functions like the one below
        $.fn.scrollPath("scrollTo", target, 1000, "easeInOutSine");
    });
});
```

So that it doesnt affect your main navigation

in demo.js

Comment: Thank you a lot Sabithpocker! That made it! :)